# Jssor Customizable

Tags: jssor

I'm using Jssor for slide a photo album but I need to know some points:

```
 1 - I need to have 4 albuns how can I switch from album to album by 4 buttons I have on right of the images

 2 - I need to configure the squares of the navigator to appear bellow each button of the album

 3 - Have the legend of each image appear below the image.
```

I need to setup something like this:
http://www.hugogomes.pt/demos/demo.jpg

```
  Thanks in advance for any tips.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Given you have 4 sliders and 4 buttons (buttons are your own outside slider), make 1 slider visible and the other 3 hidden. Detect click of buttons and switch slider to display.
2. Position of navigator is adjustable. Note that 'slides' container and navigator container are in the 'outer container'. You can adjust position (style="...top: ...px; left: ...px;") for 'slides' container and navigator container.
   Reference: http://www.jssor.com/development/tip-arrange-layout-adjust-size.html
3. Content of every slide is fully customizable. You can define slide html as <div><!-- any html code here --></div>
   Reference: http://www.jssor.com/development/define-slides-html-code.html

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your quick answer. I was trying lot of things but none of them work fine. 
I will try the way you mention. I will give feedback.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is on the TIP on site for JSSOR.

Answer for bullet are at: http://www.jssor.com/development/slider-with-bullet-navigator-jquery.html

Answer for Caption are at: http://www.jssor.com/development/slider-with-caption-jquery.html

All other things is a matter of CSS code.

Thanks for the tips.